# Solve $x^3+x^2+11x+12=0$ in $\mathbb Z/13\mathbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Could you please help me to solve $x^3+x^2+11x+12=0$ using modular arithmetic in $\left.\mathbb Z \middle/ 13\mathbb Z\right.$?

Comment: Have you tried to spot some root in $\mathbb{F}_{13}$? Once you get one, the other two follow. They are $7,8,10\pmod{13}$. You may also write the polynomial as $x^3+x^2-2x-1$ (in $\mathbb{F}_{13}$, there is no difference)

Comment: There's only 13 possible solutions. Just try them out until you find one.

Comment: I suppose you could re-write it as $x(x-1)(x+2)=1$. Usually, there isn't much you can do but try all the values. This expression lets you quickly rule out $0,1,-2$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: sorry, wrong signs. The roots are $7,8,10$.

Comment: Wofram gives you the roots $7,8,10$ so the polynomial factor as $(x-7)(x-8)(x-10)$ or, equivalently $(x+6)(x+5)(x+3)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation can be rewritten as $x^3+x^2-2x-1=0$, and we have to test the values $\pm 1,\pm 2,\pm 3,\pm4,\pm 5,\pm 6$. One finds $-5$ is a root, and *Horner's algorithm  yields the factorisation:
$$x^3+x^2-2x-1=(x+5)(x^2-4x+5).$$
The second factor can be rewritten as  $x^2-4x+5=(x-2)^2+1$, and square  roots of $-1$ in $\mathbf F_{13}$ are $\pm 5$, so $x= -3,-6$, and finally
$$x^3+x^2-2x-1=(x+3)(x+5)(x+6).$$